# Built TensorFlow successfully; example fails

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia

After successfully building TensorFlow from source, the first test example passes, and the second one fails:

1) First test: OK

```
$ python
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
>>> sess = tf.Session()
>>> print(sess.run(hello))
Hello, TensorFlow!
>>> a = tf.constant(10)
>>> b = tf.constant(32)
>>> print(sess.run(a + b))
42
```

2) Second test: FAILED
   Test file: tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py

```
$ sudo python convolutional.py
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:125] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:125] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:125] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:125] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:125] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
Successfully downloaded train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz 9912422 bytes.
Successfully downloaded train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz 28881 bytes.
Successfully downloaded t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz 1648877 bytes.
Successfully downloaded t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz 4542 bytes.
Extracting data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convolutional.py", line 339, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "convolutional.py", line 231, in main
    logits, train_labels_node))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 1684, in sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
    labels, logits)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 1533, in _ensure_xent_args
    "named arguments (labels=..., logits=..., ...)" % name)
ValueError: Only call `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` with named arguments (labels=..., logits=..., ...)
```

Since the `convolutional.py` is one of the tests reported in the installation guide, I would expect it to be fine.

I ran all the tests in the project's directory, and these are the results:

- MNIST: failed
- AlexNet: passed
- Cifar10: failed
- ImageNet: passed

Could have I done anything wrong in the build, or am I doing anything wrong in running these tests?

Reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup
Platform: Linux/Ubuntu 16.04, nVidia Quadro M6000, CUDA enabled.

Comment: I think this question is off-topic for SO. If there is any "question" there...

Comment: @Taro: I made the question more explicit.

Comment: What I understand is that your problems are specific to Tensorflow and not to some software you made. So again, I think it is off-topic, you might want to try any Tensorflow-related doc/forum.

Comment: "For help and support, technical or algorithmic questions, please submit your questions to Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow." [Reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/resources/#help_support_how_do_i)

Comment: this is not a CUDA question, it is a tensorflow question and should nt be tagged with the CUDA tag. Please stop re-adding it.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Tensorflow web site](https://www.tensorflow.org/resources/#report_issues):

> Please report bugs, feature requests and installation / compatibility issues on the TensorFlow issues tracker on GitHub.

This appears to be an installation issue and is more appropriately handled by opening an issue on GitHub.

Comment: It is not an installation issue. The program works with some data sets and not with others.

Comment: You are following the installation guide and something isn't working. That is the definition of an installation issue.